# How do i change select <option> disabled value color

Tags: html, jquery, css

I tried the below code to change the color of the select field values. how do I get the same value when the select field is disabled? kindly help.

**HTML**

```
        <div class="form-field">
            <div class="label">Product</div>
                <div class"field"><select class="select_field">
                    <option>--Select--</option>
                    <option class="colorred">one</option>
                    <option>Administrated</option>
                    <option class="colorred">Interacting</option>
                    <option>Past</option>
                </select></div></div>
```

**css**

```
.selectRedClrText{color:#f00 !important;}
.form-field label{ float:left;font-weight: bold;width:210px;}
.form-field select{ width:100%; height:28px;padding:5px;}
```

**script**

```
 jQuery(document).on("change", ".select_field", function(event){
         if($(this).find("option:selected").hasClass("colorred")){
         $(this).addClass("selectRedClrText");
          }else {
        $(this).removeClass("selectRedClrText");
        }   
        });
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you kindly elaborate on the question, please? Maybe even post a code snippet, that way we know exactly what you're asking. (A code snippet is some code that can be run in through Stack Overflow, like a codepen.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily do it with CSS:

```
 .selectRedClrText, .select_field:disabled {
    color: #f00 !important;
 }
```

If you would prefer to set it with jQuery:

```
 $(".select_field").addClass("selectRedClrText");
```

Comment: its working in chrome not in IE any idea ? thank you

Comment: @user3448925 Which version of IE? It should work since IE9 according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled

Comment: @user3448925 It's working for me in IE11 in this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m93vL4ad/

Answer (score 0):

I found an HTML Error here:

```
<div class"field">
```

May not be the root issue, but it should be fixed. Consider the following example.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".field").on("change", ".select_field", function(event) {
    if ($(this).find("option:selected").hasClass("colorred")) {
      $(this).addClass("selectRedClrText");
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass("selectRedClrText");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.selectRedClrText {
  color: #f00 !important;
}

.form-field label {
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 210px;
}

.form-field select {
  width: 100%;
  height: 28px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-field">
  <div class="label">Product</div>
  <div class="field">
    <select class="select_field">
      <option>--Select--</option>
      <option class="colorred">one</option>
      <option>Administrated</option>
      <option class="colorred">Interacting</option>
      <option>Past</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

It is best to call the parent or a closer element than `document` when delegating a callback with `.on()`.